# I want to make a connection to a database via SSH from Contenido

Tags: php, mysql, database, ssh, content-management-system

I have a Contenido-Installation on my server and cloned it locally to work on my laptop. But I want to use the same Database. The database is only reachable from the server itself. Therefore I have to tunnel a connection from Contenido via SSH to my server and access the database this why. Is there a way to establish this without changing the Contenido-Installation?

Comment: You must setup a SSH tunnel to the, this might lead you in the good direction : https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?30,249779,249779. 
NB: You should never use a production database for developement.

Comment: Thank you for your concern. But the whole project is in development at the moment. So there is no problem with using the same database. The problem is I do not want to alter the Contenido-Installation and thought maybe Contenido has a mechanism to establish tunneled SSH-connection to a mysql database. If not I guess I have to alter it to get the problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing to change in your cms. On the Server, establish an ssh tunnel:

ssh -L localport:dest_server:dest_port -l username tunnelserver

**But Live can be easier!**

I currently use xst_dev for this. It's an docker enviroment which gives you phpfarm (means multiple phpversions by portswitch) and mysql at your desktop. All you have to to is to adjust one File (config.xst) and copy your webproject and a sqldump to yor workstation and run xst_dev

The whole live-enviroment (in this case your contenido cms) runs without any changes at your contenido configs.

I looking forward to create an productpage for xst_dev soon.